# Index view is not redirected and not refreshed after save button on create view is clicked. But data is saved successfully

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Screen is not redirected to Index view and data is not refreshed after save button click on create view. But data is saved successfully. How can I redirect and refresh index view after data is saved.

TestController

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CRUDMVCAngularJS.Models;

namespace CRUDMVCAngularJS.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        private SchoolEntities db = new SchoolEntities();

        // GET: Test
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        // GET: All Students
        public JsonResult GetAllStudent()
        {
            var studentList = db.Students.ToList();
            return Json(studentList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


        //GET: Student by Id
        public JsonResult GetStudentById(string id)
        {
            var studentId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            var getStudentById = db.Students.Find(studentId);
            return Json(getStudentById, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }

        // Add Student
        public string AddStudent(Student student)
        {
            if (student != null)
            {
                using (SchoolEntities contextObj = new SchoolEntities())
                {
                    contextObj.Students.Add(student);
                    contextObj.SaveChanges();
                    return "Student record added successfully";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "Invalid student record";
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Index View

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>
    <div ng-controller="mvcCRUDCtrl">
        <p>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Add" ng-click="AddStudentDiv()" />

        </p>
        <div class="divList">
            <p><b><i>Employee List</i></b></p>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <td><b>ID</b></td>
                    <td><b>FirstName</b></td>
                    <td><b>LastName</b></td>
                    <td><b>Age</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
                    <td>
                        {{student.Id}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{student.FirstName}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{student.LastName}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{student.Age}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span ng-click="editBook(book)" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</span>
                        <span ng-click="deleteBook(book)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

Create View

<div ng-controller="mvcCRUDCtrl">
    <p class="divHead"></p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td><b>FirstName</b></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="FirstName" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>LastName</b></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="LastName" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Age</b></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="Age" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Save" ng-click="AddUpdateStudent()" />
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cancel" ng-click="Cancel()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mvcCRUDApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/StudentScripts/Module.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/StudentScripts/Controller.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/StudentScripts/Service.js")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

AngularJS Module

```
var app = angular.module("mvcCRUDApp", []);
```

AngularJS Service

```
app.service("crudAJService", function ($http) {

    //get All Students
    this.getStudents = function () {
        return $http.get("../Test/GetAllStudent");
    };

    // get Student by studentId
    this.getStudent = function (studentId) {
        debugger;
        var response = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "../Test/GetStudentById",
            params: {
                id: JSON.stringify(studentId)
            }
        });
        return response;
    }

    // Add Student
    this.AddStudent = function (student) {
        debugger;
        var response = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "../Test/AddStudent",
            data: JSON.stringify(student),
            dataType: "json"
        });
        return response;
    }

});
```

AngularJS Controller

```
app.controller("mvcCRUDCtrl", function ($scope, crudAJService) {
    GetAllStudents();
    //To Get all student records  
    function GetAllStudents() {
        var getStudentData = crudAJService.getStudents();
        getStudentData.then(function (student) {
            $scope.students = student.data;
        }, function () {
            alert('Error in getting student records');
        });
    }


    $scope.AddUpdateStudent = function () {
        $scope.Action = "Add";
        debugger;
        var Student = {
            FirstName: $scope.FirstName,
            LastName: $scope.LastName,
            Age: $scope.Age
        };
        var getAction = $scope.Action;

        if (getAction == "Update") {
            Student.Id = $scope.Id;
            var getData = crudAJService.updateStudent(Student);
            getData.then(function (msg) {
                GetAllStudents();
                alert(msg.data);
            }, function () {
                alert('Error in updating record');
            });
        } else {
            var getData = crudAJService.AddStudent(Student);
            getData.then(function (msg) {
                GetAllStudents();
                alert(msg.data);
            }, function () {
                alert('Error in adding record');
            });
        }
    }

    $scope.AddStudentDiv = function () {
        ClearFields();
        window.location = "../Test/Create";
    }

    function ClearFields() {
        $scope.Id = "";
        $scope.FirstName = "";
        $scope.LastName = "";
        $scope.Age = "";
    }

    $scope.Cancel = function () {
        window.location = "../Test/Index";
    };
});
```

Comment: On `AddStudent` just use `.success` call back to redirect - e.g. `.success(function(){ window.location = "/Test/Index"; })`

Comment: Please suggest how can i modify code

Comment: @JamesP I tried this and page redirects to Index view but the data is still old. I mean the newly added data is not refreshed on index view

Comment: @JamesP How can use .sucess on AddStudent

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about view not binding two-way when new students are added, did you call the get all students and reassign to scope after successfully adding students so that it will render the change on UI

Answer (score 0):

To redirect after adding a student record, put `window.location = "/Test/Index";` on `AddUpdateStudent` if success :

```
$scope.AddUpdateStudent = function () {
        $scope.Action = "Add";
        debugger;
        var Student = {
            FirstName: $scope.FirstName,
            LastName: $scope.LastName,
            Age: $scope.Age
        };
        var getAction = $scope.Action;

        if (getAction == "Update") {
            Student.Id = $scope.Id;
            var getData = crudAJService.updateStudent(Student);
            getData.then(function (msg) {

                alert(msg.data);
                window.location = "/Test/Index";  // redirect
            }, function () {
                alert('Error in updating record');
            });
        } else {
            var getData = crudAJService.AddStudent(Student);
            getData.then(function (msg) {

                alert(msg.data);
            }, function () {
                alert('Error in adding record');
            });
        }
    }
```

To display refreshed student data I think you need to get student data at first hand and bind it through `ng-repeat`

In Index view I would use `ng-init` to initialize getting data :

```
<div ng-controller="mvcCRUDCtrl" ng-init = "GetAllStudents()">
```

And in controller :

```
app.controller("mvcCRUDCtrl", function ($scope, crudAJService) {

  $scope.GetAllStudents = function() {
        var getStudentData = crudAJService.getStudents();
           getStudentData.then(function (student) {
        $scope.students = student.data;
        }, function () {
           alert('Error in getting student records');
        });
  }
```

Comment: Data is still not refreshed on Index View

Comment: Have you got any idea still